# A regex to match a substring that isn't followed by a certain other substring

Tags: java, regex, clojure

I need a regex that will match `blahfooblah` but not `blahfoobarblah`

I want it to match only foo and everything around foo, as long as it isn't followed by bar.

I tried using this: `foo.*(?<!bar)` which is fairly close, but it matches `blahfoobarblah`. The negative look behind needs to match anything and not just bar.

The specific language I'm using is Clojure which uses Java regexes under the hood.

EDIT: More specifically, I also need it to pass `blahfooblahfoobarblah` but not `blahfoobarblahblah`.

Comment: Did you try using foo.*(?<!bar.*) ?

Answer (score 194, accepted):

#### Try:

```
/(?!.*bar)(?=.*foo)^(\w+)$/
```

#### Tests:

```
blahfooblah            # pass
blahfooblahbarfail     # fail
somethingfoo           # pass
shouldbarfooshouldfail # fail
barfoofail             # fail
```

#### Regular expression explanation

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    .*                       any character except \n (0 or more times
                             (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    bar                      'bar'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    .*                       any character except \n (0 or more times
                             (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    foo                      'foo'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \w+                      word characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _) (1 or
                             more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                           string
```

#### Other regex

If you only want to exclude `bar` when it is directly after `foo`, you can use

```
/(?!.*foobar)(?=.*foo)^(\w+)$/
```

---

#### Edit

You made an update to your question to make it specific.

```
/(?=.*foo(?!bar))^(\w+)$/
```

#### New tests

```
fooshouldbarpass               # pass
butnotfoobarfail               # fail
fooshouldpassevenwithfoobar    # pass
nofuuhere                      # fail
```

#### New explanation

`(?=.*foo(?!bar))` ensures a `foo` is found but is not followed directly `bar`

Comment: This is very close, and a very good answer. I knew I wouldn't be specific enough. :( I need this: "blahfoomeowwoof/foobar/" to pass because of the lonely "foo", but not this blahfoobarmeowwoof If this is possible.

Comment: As a side question, how would one go about matching something like "bot" but not "botters"?

Comment: Yes. I can use what I have now, but it would be easier if I could just match bot but not botters. I'm very sorry. I'm inexperienced with regexes, and I'm afraid I'm slowly figuring out what I want myself. :p

Comment: @Rayne, this is the same question. In your above example, you wanted to match `foo` but not `foobar`. To match `bot` but not `botters`, you would use `/(?=.*bot(?!ters))^(\w+)$/`.

Comment: Well, I was generally aiming towards whole words. Like I said, I'm confused about what I really want and what is really possible. Doing it like this will work. Thank you for time. :)

Comment: I'm using this code for a similar regex

(?=.*did you(?!say))

that looks for instances of the string "did you" so long as it isn't followed by "say". It currently matches "did you think" but not "did you" in isolation. Any thoughts on what the problem is here?

Comment: what is the forward slash / at the beginning and end of the RegEx for?

Answer (score 64):

To match a `foo` following by something that doesn't start with `bar`, try

```
foo(?!bar)
```

Your version with negative lookbehind is effectively "match a `foo` followed by something that doesn't end in `bar`". The `.*` matches all of `barblah`, and the `(?<!bar)` looks back at `lah` and checks that it doesn't match `bar`, which it doesn't, so the whole pattern matches.

Comment: So I tried this for a regex that's designed to match the string "did you" so long as it isn't followed by "say". It works when differentiating between "did you say" and "did you think", for example, but just "did you" by itself doesn't get captured, and it should. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Use a negative look ahead instead:

```
\s*(?!\w*(bar)\w*)\w*(foo)\w*\s*
```

This worked for me, hope it helps. Good luck!

Comment: Simple yet effective regex, which also works for excluding repeating strings ("foofoo"). Perfect!

Answer (score 1):

You wrote a comment suggesting you like this to work matching all words in a string rather than the whole string itself.

Rather than mashing all of this in a comment, I'm posting it as a new answer.

#### New Regex

```
/(?=\w*foo(?!bar))(\w+)/
```

#### Sample text

> foowithbar fooevenwithfoobar notfoobar foohere notfoobarhere butfooisokherebar notfoobarhere andnofuu needsfoo

#### Matches

> foowithbar fooevenwithfoobar foohere butfooisokherebar needsfoo

Answer (score 0):

Your specific match request can be matched by:

```
\w+foo(?!bar)\w+
```

This will match `blahfooblahfoobarblah` but not `blahfoobarblahblah`.

The problem with your regex of `foo.*(?<!bar)` is the `.*` after `foo`. It matches as many of any characters including characters after `bar`.