# How to match the character '<' not followed by ('a' or 'em' or 'strong')?

Tags: javascript, regex

How would I make a regular expression to match the character `<` not followed by (`a` or `em` or `strong`)

So `<hello` and `<string` would match, but `<strong` wouldn't.

Comment: **See Also**: [A regex to match a substring that isn't followed by a certain other substring](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2631010/1366033)

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Try this:

```
<(?!a|em|strong)
```

Comment: +1 I think that does it for Perl-compatible regexp syntax. (For other syntaxes, it might be different)

Comment: Just in case someone is interested, `?!` initiates a negative lookahead. I found a good overview of lookarounds here: http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html

Comment: For a full function: `myString.replace(/<(?!\/?(a|em|strong)).*?>/g, '');`
I also added in `\/?` to check for closing tags

Answer (score 11):

You use a [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), the simplest form for which is (for this problem):

```
<(?!a|em|strong)
```

The one issue with that is that it will ignore `<applet>`. A way to deal with that is by using `\b`, which is a zero-width expression (meaning it captures none of the input) that matches a word to non-word or non-word to word transition. Word characters are `[0-9a-zA-Z_]`. So:

```
<(?!(a|em|strong)\b)
```

Answer (score 3):

Although Andrew's answer is clearly superior, before, I also got it to work with `[^(?:a|em|strong)]`.

Answer (score 2):

If your regex engine supports it, use a negative lookahead assertion: this looks ahead in the string, and succeeds if it wouldn't match; however, it doesn't consume any input.  Thus, you want  `/<(?!(?:a|em|strong)\b)/`: match a `<`, then succeed if there isn't an `a`, `em`, or `strong` followed by a word break, `\b`.

Comment: Interesting point about the word break, although the OP didn't say whether that was desired

Answer (score 0):

```
function strip_tags(str, keep){
    if(keep && Array.isArray(keep)){keep = '|'+keep.join('|');}else if(keep){keep = '|'+keep;}else{keep = '';}
    return str.replace(new RegExp('<\/?(?![^A-Za-z0-9_\-]'+keep+').*?>', 'g'), '');
}
```

usage:

```
strip_tags('<html><a href="a">a</a> <strong>strong text</strong> and <em>italic text</em></html>', ['strong', 'em']);
//output: a <strong>strong text</strong> and <em>italic text</em>
```

I would also recommend you strip parameters from the tags you keep

```
function strip_params(str){
    return str.replace(/<((?:[A-Za-z0-9_\-])).*?>/g, '<$1>');
}
```