# Replace string with condition in google script

Tags: javascript, regex

in google script I am trying to replace a `%`string basing on the character following it.

I've tried using:

```
var indexOfPercent = newString.indexOf("%");
```

and then check the character of `indexOfPercent+1`, but `indexOf` returns only the first occurrence of '%'.

How can I get all occurrences? Maybe there is easier way to do that (regular expressions)?

---

EDIT:

Finally I want to replace all my `%` occurrences to `%%`, but not if percent sign was part of `%@` or `%@`.

To sum up: my string: `Test%@ Test2%s Test3%.` should look like:  `Test%@ Test2%s Test3%%.`

I've tried using something like this:

```
  //?!n Matches any string that is not followed by a specific string n
  //(x|y)   Find any of the alternatives specified
  var newString = newString.replace(\%?![s]|\%?![%], "%%")
```

but it didn't find any strings. I am not familiar with regex's, so maybe it is a simple mistake.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
// replace all '%'
var StrPercent = '%100%ffff%';
var StrNoPersent = StrPercent.replace(/\%/g,'');
Logger.log(StrNoPersent); // 100ffff
```

Look for [more info here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp)

---

**Edit**

In your case you need RegEx with the character not followed by group of characters. Similiar question was asked here:

[Regular expressions - how to match the character '<' not followed by ('a' or 'em' or 'strong')?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2706745/regular-expressions-how-to-match-the-character-not-followed-by-a-or-em)

Thy this code:

```
function RegexNotFollowedBy() {

var sample = ['Test%@',
              'Test2%s',
              'Test3%',
              '%Test4%'];

var RegEx = /%(?!s|@)/g;
var Replace = "%%";

var str, newStr;

  for (var i = 0; i < sample.length; i++) {
      str = sample[i];
      newStr = str.replace(RegEx, Replace);
      Logger.log(newStr);

  }

}
```

I'll explain expression `/%(?!s|@)/g`:

- `%` -- look '%'
- `(text1|text2|text3...|textN)` -- not followed by text1, 2 etc.
- `g` -- look for any accurance of searched text

Comment: Thanks a lot. It did solve problem of finding all occurrences of % sign, but still I want to use regular expression to check condition of following character. See the edit.

Comment: I've addeted the answer.