# Regular expression, ignore line when next character is a "-"

Tags: regex

If `[\s\d]*` means: repeat matching space-character or digit. What would be the syntax for ignoring the entire line if there suddenly is a `"-"` character?

Like in this example https://regex101.com/r/eP1kG1/1
The last line should not match!

`.*\bAPPLE.*\bPIE[\s\d]*`

`SWEET APPLE 1 - PIE 2
SWEET APPLE 1 - PIE 2 IS GOOD
SWEET APPLE 1 - PIE3
SWEET APPLE 1 - PIE 1-3 IS GOOD`

Only the last line should not match, meaning: When there is a "-" after PIE it should fail.

Also this is for sql, and not possible to use look-ahead/behind

Comment: What have you tried so far? By the way, we should not have to leave SO to see what you mean.

Comment: $, [^-] even groups, but it fails since [^-] means a character but not a "-"

Comment: your question is not clear. please state what your your problem is, sample input and expected outputs. it is also important in which context do you intend to use it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [A regex to match a substring that isn't followed by a certain other substring](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2631010/a-regex-to-match-a-substring-that-isnt-followed-by-a-certain-other-substring)

Comment: @stribizhev That line is fine. It's just the last one that is incorrect

Comment: _this is for sql_ - What DBMS are you using as the answer could vary. And also if this is for a Select statement why not specify it in the where clause.

Comment: @JavaDevil Oracle sql developer. I'm using the regexp_like method in a where clause

Comment: You can try another approach: disallow `-` up to the string end: `^.*\bAPPLE.*\bPIE[\s\d]*[^-]*$`. See https://regex101.com/r/eP1kG1/3. Look-arounds are "expensive".

Comment: @stribizhev Nice one! You should post that one as an answer! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment, look-aheads usually consume much more computing power. I'd suggest the following regex:

```
^.*\bAPPLE.*\bPIE[\s\d]*[^-]*$
```

It just requires all characters after `[\s\d]*` to be non-hyphens. Anchors - `^` and `$` -  make sure we only check the whole string.

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/eP1kG1/3).

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want? Just checking to make sure `PIE[\s\d]*` isn't followed by a `-` on the line:

```
(?!.*PIE[\s\d]*-).*\bAPPLE.*\bPIE[\s\d]*
```

Comment: Exactly, just need to test this in sql. 
Maybe my [\s\d]* isn't the best way because there can be other valid characters after, like in line two....