# Building a regular expression that tests true for '!=' but false for '!'

Tags: regex

I'm looking to allow the inequality operator, but disallow the special character '!' on its own.

Maybe I can use two regular expressions, /!=/ and /!/. I want to test for /!/ if it is alone - and output an error if it isn't accompanied by an equal sign. The issue is that /!/ will test true if the input is '!='. Thoughts?

Input: "!= !"

Expected Output: "Token '!=' Found

Invalid Character '!' Found

Comment: Please mention your inputs strings and expected output strings.

Comment: Why use a regex for a fixed value? You may just check if there is a `!=`. If you need to check if a string has `!` not followed with `=`, yes, use `/!(?!=)/` regex.

Comment: @Azurasky Are you expecting this https://regex101.com/r/74iVXd/1?

Comment: I am using a regular expression so that I can test for the presence of these values in a string that could potentially be very long.

Comment: `(?=!(?!\=))`? "foo ! bar" matches, "foo != bar" does not

Comment: I still need to check if it contains `!` by itself. Which is an issue because a single exclamation mark is also a part of the inequality operator `!=`.

Comment: Use `/!(?!=)/` regex.

Comment: Crusy - can you elaborate on that a little more on that and maybe put it in an answer? I'm a novice when it comes to regular expressions and would appreciate a walkthrough on how you came up with that.

Comment: Wiktor - Same as above, could you walk me through how you come up with that and why you believe it is the ideal solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a [**negative lookahead**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to make sure some pattern is not found to the right of the current location:

```
/!(?!=)/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/a7Y0sK/1). Here, `!` is only matched if there is no `=` immediately after it.

See more about [how negative lookahead works here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31201690/find-word-not-followed-by/31201710#31201710).

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand you want to search for a character ! which is NOT followed by a character =. That sounds similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2631010/3890673). I tried [here](https://regex101.com/r/PY4NtP/1):

```
// regex (?=!(?!\=))

!= ! // matches
foo ! bar // matches
foo != bar // doesn't match
```

The keyword here is [lookaround](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). See details there (and in the question I linked).