# Regexp - match pattern except if it's part of another pattern

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I'm trying to look for word *"error"* in various log files that don't have a fixed structure and at the same time ignore known false positives. Take for example a log line like this:

```
21:55:50 [wsgi:error] [/app/whatever.py] debug: Harmless message
21:55:50 [wsgi:error] [/app/somethingelse.py] error: Problem message
```

I want to match lines containing `error` but not if it's only `wsgi:error`, i.e. only match the second line.

I *don't* want to split the line by space and only match e.g. from 3rd field on because I've got some mixed up log files where we've got messages from different sources and the format is not as nice as above.

I'm looking probably for a way to essentially do:

*Match if the line says "error" or "fatal" but not if the only match is "wsgi:error" or "problem is not fatal".* You get my point.

At the moment I replace all the whitelisted patterns with 'xxxx' and only then look for errors but that's quite a dirty solution. I'm hoping for a better one :)

Ideally in Python 3.6+, perhaps with some regexp magic?

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you expand on `problem is not fatal`?  Are there a list of problem occurrences which should be discounted?

Comment: Try: `egrep "^.*\berror:.*$" your_log_file`

Comment: You can use a variation of this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2631032/3803979

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen that *"problem is not fatal"* is just another false positive pattern that I don't want to match. I will have a list of such false positives.

Comment: Then include that list in your question.  You can't expect an answer without sharing enough information for someone to help you.