# Replace characters in a PHP string skipping specific domain extensions

Tags: php, regex, replace, preg-replace, str-replace

I have a long string and would like to replace every dot "." with a question mark, however my string includes domain extensions such as .com which I would like to skip when replacing.

Is there any way I can provide an array such as (".com", ".net", ".org") of phrases to skip when replacing using str_replace() or a similar function?

Input sentence:

```
$string = "An example of a website would be google.com or similar. However this is not what we are looking for";
```

The following:

```
str_replace(".", "?", $string);
```

Produces:

```
An example of a website would be google?com or similar? However this is not what we are looking for
```

Desired output:

```
An example of a website would be google.com or similar? However this is not what we are looking for
```

I would like to provide an array of domain extensions to skip, when replacing. Such as:

```
$skip = array(".com",".net",".org");
```

and wherever those appear, don't substitute the dot with a question mark.

EDIT: Looks like I need to use a negative lookahead with preg_replace. However not sure how to put it all together: "look for a full stop that is NOT followed by COM or NET or ORG.

Comment: You've tagged this with regex and preg replace. Have you tried using regex? I don't see it in your question.

Comment: I am not sure what regex to use for it, and can't find anything.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2631010/a-regex-to-match-a-substring-that-isnt-followed-by-a-certain-other-substring, namely https://stackoverflow.com/a/2631107/3832970

Comment: Have you done any real research into regex, how it works and tried anything? [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/) is a very good site for testing (and learning) regex.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yes, I've already seen that link, however I'm not sure how to apply it to my needs. Looks like I need to use a negative lookahead, such as (?!.*bar) however not sure how to combine it with: Look for a full stop > that isn't followed by COM or ORG or NET. Can anyone help please?

Comment: No need using `.*`, you want to match something right after a char. BTW, [here is how to match a dot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13989640/regular-expression-to-match-a-dot).

Comment: I would split the string by values from the $skip array,
then deleted everything that was not needed.
Then I would restore the string by gluing the elements of the array using the extensions from $skip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need

```php
$result = preg_replace('~\.(?!(?:com|org|net)\b)~', '?', $string);
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/9jcmyO/1).
*Details*

- `\.` - a dot
- `(?!`  - not followed with

  - `(?:com|org|net)` - `com`, `org`, `net` substrings...
  - `\b` - as whole words (it is a word boundary)
- `)` - end of the negative lookahead.

**NOTE**: to make the TLDs match in a case insensitive way, add `i` after the trailing regex delimiter, here, `~i`.

See a [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/mLXjc):

```php
$string = "An example of a website would be google.com or similar. However this is not what we are looking for";
$tlds = ['com', 'org', 'net'];
echo preg_replace('~\.(?!(?:' . implode('|', $tlds) . ')\b)~i', '?', $string);
// => An example of a website would be google.com or similar? However this is not what we are looking for
```