# Regex to match a substring if it is not followed by another string

Tags: regex

First of all, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2631010/a-regex-to-match-a-substring-that-isnt-followed-by-a-certain-other-substring) does not work for my question. **EDIT**: I use Golang, whose regex support is documented [here](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax).

I am writing a schema management tool for mysql, which I need to do a replace from:

```
CREATE TABLE `sometable`
```

to

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sometable`
```

Originally, I just use `CREATE TABLE\s+` to do the match, but in some case it will generate result like:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS IF NOT EXISTS `sometable`
```

So I consider to write an regular expression to match **CREATE TABLE** when and only when it is *not* followed by **IF NOT EXISTS**.  More precisely, if the string is `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS`, I want the regex to NOT match it at all, rather than match the CREATE TABLE in it.

Comment: just try to match the whole line instead of doing it partially

Answer (score 0):

I found out this works:

```
CREATE TABLE(?! IF NOT EXISTS)
```

which is tested on https://regexr.com/, HOWEVER the `?!` operator is NOT supprorted by Go.

Comment: It won't work if the TABLE followed by two or more spaces

Comment: better try this `CREATE TABLE(?!\s+IF\s+NOT\s+EXISTS)`